# How to store an array to mysql using PHP INSERT with same variable value for id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

So I'm trying to store values for my _SESSION array which is making the cart within my website work. I'm having trouble INSERTING the same array to my database - I guess I have same id for multiple arrays so that's why it's not working. That's my guess. I hope someone can help me.

Here's my first attempt at trying.

```html
<?

$con = mysql_connect('bluecubecreatives.net', 'bluecu6_user', '*****');  if (!$con)  {    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }
  mysql_select_db("bluecu6_databasename", $con);
  
$itemsupdate =  "INSERT INTO orderitems (ID, ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, NAME, QUANTITY, SIZE, FOR, PRICE, TOTAL)
VALUES (NULL, '$id', '$item_stock_id', '$item_name', '$item_quantity', '$item_size', '$item_for', '$item_price', '$item_total');";
mysql_query($itemsupdate);

?>
```

and here's my second try at fixing it.

```html
$additems = array ('ID' => NULL, 'ORDER_ID' => $item_id, 'ITEM_ID' => $item_stock_id, 'NAME' => $item_name, 'QUANTITY' => $item_quantity, 'SIZE' => $item_size, 'FOR' => $item_for, 'PRICE' => $item_price, 'TOTAL' => $item_total);

$update =  "INSERT INTO orderitems (ID, ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, NAME, QUANTITY, SIZE, FOR, PRICE, TOTAL) VALUES";

$it = new ArrayIterator( $additems );
    // a new caching iterator gives us access to hasNext()
    $cit = new CachingIterator( $it );
    // loop over the array
    foreach ( $cit as $value )
    {
        // add to the query
        $sql .= "('".$cit->key()."','" .$cit->current()."')";
        // if there is another array member, add a comma
        if( $cit->hasNext() )
        {
            $sql .= ",";
        }
    }
```

HERE's  the full code where I'm trying to push the SESSION items and the billing + shipping details to my database.

```html
$connection = mysql_connect('bluecubecreatives.net', 'bluecu6', '****'); 
$selected = mysql_select_db("bluecu6", $connection)  or die("Hello ONE, Sorry! This AI system couldn't connect to your database.");
if (!$connection) {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
} else { $id = 1; }

if (isset($_GET['size'])) {
$size = $_GET['size'];
} else { $size = "Standard"; }

if (isset($_GET['quantity'])) {
$quantity = $_GET['quantity'];
$cart_update = 1;
} else { $quantity = 0; $cart_update = 0; }


if (isset($_GET['for'])) {
$for = $_GET['for'];
} else { $for = "All Purpose"; }

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
$action = $_GET['action'];
} else { $action="empty";
}

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID= '" . $id . "';" ,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$val = mysql_fetch_array($data);


if ($action=="add") {
$newitem = array ('id' => $id , 'name' => $val['PRO_NAME'], 'quantity' => $quantity, 'size' => $size,'for' => $for,'price' => $val['PRO_RS']);
$_SESSION['item'][$id] = $newitem;
}

$_SESSION['quantity'] = $_SESSION['quantity'] + $cart_update;
$in_cart = $_SESSION['quantity'];
$_SESSION['cart_total'] = $in_cart;

if ($_SESSION['cart_total'] <=0) {
 $_SESSION['cart_total'] = 0;
}

if ($id!=0) {
 
switch($action) {
 
 case "view":
 if  (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
 $_SESSION['cart'][$id];
 }  else {
 $_SESSION['cart'][$id]=0;
 } break;
 
 
 case "refresh";
  session_destroy();
 break;
 
 case "delete";
 if  ($_SESSION['cart_total']==1) {
  $_SESSION['cart_total']=0;
  unset($_SESSION['item']);
  session_destroy();
 } 
 else if ($_SESSION['cart_total']>1) {
  $_SESSION['quantity']--;
  $_SESSION['cart_total']--;
  unset($_SESSION['item'][$id]);
 } break;
 
 case "add":
 if  (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
 $_SESSION['cart'][$id]++;
 } else {
 $_SESSION['cart'][$id]=1;
 } break;
 
 case "remove";
 if  (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
 $_SESSION['cart'][$id]--;
 
  if ($_SESSION['cart'][$id]==0) {
  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]); 
  $_SESSION['cart_total']--;
  }
  if ($_SESSION['cart'][$id]==-1) {
  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
  $_SESSION['cart_total']--;
  }
 } break;
 
 case "empty";
 unset($_SESSION['cart']);
 $_SESSION['cart_total'] = 0;
 break;
}

}

if($_POST['ADD_TOCONFIRM']){  

$shipping_option = $_POST['shipping_option'];$payment_option = $_POST['payment_option'];$discount_val = $_POST['discount_val'];

$bname = $_POST['name'];$baddress = $_POST['address'];$bcity = $_POST['city'];$bprovince = $_POST['province'];$bzip = $_POST['zip'];
$bcountry = $_POST['country'];$bcontact = $_POST['contact'];$bemail = $_POST['email'];

$sname = $_POST['sname'];$saddress = $_POST['saddress'];$scity = $_POST['scity'];$sprovince = $_POST['sprovince'];$szip = $_POST['szip'];
$scountry = $_POST['scountry'];$scontact = $_POST['scontact'];$semail = $_POST['semail'];

$status = "Pending";

//

foreach ( $_SESSION['item'] AS $data ) {
  
$xo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID= '" . $data['id'] . "';" ,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$yo = mysql_fetch_array($xo);

$l_cost = $data['price'] * $data['quantity'];
$t_cost = $t_cost + $l_cost;
$t_bill = $t_cost;

$item_id =  (int) $id;
$item_stock_id = (int) $yo['ID'];
$item_name = $yo['PRO_NAME'];
$item_size = $data['size']; 
$item_for = $data['for']; 
$item_quantity = (int) $data['quantity']; 
$item_price = (int) $yo['PRO_RS'];
$item_total = (int) $l_cost;
  
$con = mysql_connect('bluecubecreatives.net', 'bluecu6', '***');  if (!$con)  {    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }
mysql_select_db("bluecu6", $con);
  
$itemsupdate =  "INSERT INTO orderitems (ID, ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, NAME, QUANTITY, SIZE, FOR, PRICE, TOTAL)
VALUES (NULL, '$item_id', '$item_stock_id', '$item_name', '$item_quantity', '$item_size', '$item_for', '$item_price', '$item_total');";

mysql_query($itemsupdate);

echo '<br />'; 
echo $item_id. '<br />';
echo $item_stock_id. '<br />';  
echo $item_name. '<br />';  
echo $item_size. '<br />'; 
echo $item_for. '<br />'; 
echo $item_quantity. '<br />'; 
echo $item_price. '<br />';
echo $item_total. '<br />';
 
 }


if (($shipping_option!=="")&&($payment_option!=="")&&($bname!=="")&&($baddress!=="")&&($bcity!=="")&&($bprovince!=="")&&($bzip!=="")&&($bcountry!=="")&&($bcontact!=="")&&($bemail!=="")) {
 
$con = mysql_connect('bluecubecreatives.net', 'bluecu6', '*****');  if (!$con)  {    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }
  mysql_select_db("bluecu6", $con);
  
  $query = 
 "INSERT INTO orders (ORDER_ID, SHIP_OPTION, PAY_OPTION, DISCOUNT, NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, PROVINCE, ZIP, COUNTRY, CONTACT, EMAIL, NAME_SHIP, ADDRESS_SHIP, CITY_SHIP, PROVINCE_SHIP, ZIP_SHIP, COUNTRY_SHIP, CONTACT_SHIP, EMAIL_SHIP, STATUS)

VALUES (NULL, '$shipping_option', '$payment_option', '$discount_val', '$bname', '$baddress', '$bcity', '$bprovince', '$bzip', '$bcountry', '$bcontact', '$bemail', '$sname', '$saddress', '$scity', '$sprovince', '$szip', '$scountry', '$scontact', '$semail' , '$status');";



mysql_query($query);
echo '<br />'; 
echo "success". '<br />';
echo '<br />'; 
echo $shipping_option. '<br />';  
echo $payment_option. '<br />'; 
echo $discount_val. '<br />'; 
echo '<br />'; 
echo $bname. '<br />'; 
echo $baddress. '<br />'; 
echo $bcity. '<br />'; 
echo $bprovince. '<br />'; 
echo $bzip. '<br />'; 
echo $bcountry. '<br />'; 
echo $bcontact. '<br />'; 
echo $bemail. '<br />'; 
echo '<br />'; 
echo $sname. '<br />'; 
echo $saddress. '<br />'; 
echo $scity. '<br />'; 
echo $sprovince. '<br />'; 
echo $szip. '<br />'; 
echo $scountry. '<br />'; 
echo $scontact. '<br />'; 
echo $semail. '<br />'; 
echo '<br />'; 
echo $total_bill. '<br />';
//echo mysql_query($newitem). '<br />';

foreach ( $_SESSION['item'] AS $item ) 
{  
 echo 'id: ' . $item['id'] . ' - ';  echo 'name: ' . $item['name'] . ' - '; echo 'quantity: ' . $item['quantity'] . ' - '; echo 'size: ' . $item['size'] . ' - ';  echo 'price: ' . $item['price'] . ' - ';  echo 'for: ' . $item['for'] . '<br />';
 
  $line_cost = $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];
 $total_cost = $total_cost + $line_cost;
 $total_bill = $total_cost;
} 
 
 echo '<br />'; echo '<br />';
 echo $total_bill;
 echo '<br />'; echo '<br />';


mysql_close($con);


} else {
echo "please fill all options";
}

}
```

Comment: don't use mysql_ functions use PDO http://in3.php.net/pdo

Comment: Can you print your session and paste that in? `print_r($_SESSION)`. Star (***) sensitive info.

Comment: Yes I can print it and it's working fine. my _SESSIONS are working on all pages. The only issue I'm having is to make the session array store all the info on mysql database using PHP. The thing is, for 2 items in cart (with current session), it only generate 1 id for both - maybe that is causing the problem when I INSERT it to my table - where it uses similar id for 2 or more items.

Comment: For example, when I echo all the values for the array - if there are 2 items. This is how it shows. 
"""FIRST ONE = 
0
1
Ajrak
Medium
Girls
3
750
2250
| SECOUND ONE =
0
2
Product Name
Medium
Guys
3
750
2250

You can see they both have the same cart ID (0), but a different product id.

Comment: I know but it's hard to confirm what you are saying you think the problem is if you don't show what your `$_SESSION` looks like. You are saying the session is the problem but I don't know what your session looks like so I can't really help you out. Your explanations are too abstract without seeing it. It makes sense to you because you are looking at it...

Comment: So I'm running this command in with in this foreach ( $_SESSION['item'] AS $data ) { }

Let me update my code so you can go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose if you have following array,

```
$additems = array ('ID' => NULL, 'ORDER_ID' => $item_id, 'ITEM_ID' => $item_stock_id, 'NAME' => $item_name, 'QUANTITY' => $item_quantity, 'SIZE' => $item_size, 'FOR' => $item_for, 'PRICE' => $item_price, 'TOTAL' => $item_total);
```

you can perform your query like

```
$update =  "INSERT INTO orderitems (ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, NAME, QUANTITY, SIZE, FOR, PRICE, TOTAL) VALUES ($additems['ORDER_ID'],$additems['ITEM_ID'],$additems['NAME'],$additems['QUANTITY'],$additems['SIZE'],$additems['FOR'],$additems['PRICE'],$additems['TOTAL'])";
```

try this, this should work.
feel free to ask if you got any problem with this.

Comment: Thanks Anand. This is basically what I'm doing but it doesn't seem to work. I'm assigning each $additem variable to another constant and using that to push the values as you can see in my code above.

Comment: what is your actual problem? your record is not inserting right? i think you id is duplicating.it is inserting 0 every time. do one thing insert record without using id.

Comment: yep that's my actual problem. I tried that and it didn't work. I have auto increment for ID for mysql database. So i suppose even if the id (order) for 2 items is the same, it should record as there should be a new id for each submission on the backend.

Comment: i have updated query in my ans, i removed id please check if it is working. otherwise print your query and perform that query in phpmyadmin sql area, check if you getting any error there?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what was wrong with my code. I extracted the INSERT code from mysql and configured it in my PHP file. All of a sudden, it all started working.

```html
$itemupdate = "INSERT INTO `orderitems`(`SESSION_ID`, `ORDER_ID`, `ITEM_ID`, `NAME`, `QUANTITY`, `SIZE`, `FOR`, `PRICE`, `TOTAL`, `NOTES`) 

VALUES ('$session_no','$item_id','$item_stock_id','$item_name','$item_quantity','$item_size','$item_for','$item_price','$item_total','notes');";

mysql_query($itemupdate);
```